# Adding @Convert on column increases execution time by more then 10 times

Tags: java, hibernate, security

I have the following entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Customer\"")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="customer_id_seq",
            sequenceName="customer_id_seq",
            allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator="customer_id_seq")
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    @Convert(converter = LastNameEncryption.class)
    private String lastName;
}
```

Where `LastNameEncryption.java` is:

```
public class LastNameEncryption implements AttributeConverter<String,String> {

    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private final static String peselKey = "somekey";

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        try
        {
            setKey();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(attribute.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;

    }

    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        try {
            setKey();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(dbData)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;

    }

    public static void setKey() {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        byte[] key;
        try {
            key = peselKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Which should act as an ecnryption/decryption mechanism.

However, when I added this, the execution time of the simple queries increased from around 200ms to 5.5s (original topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971793/what-is-wrong-with-my-entity-that-it-is-loading-super-slow/39971898#39971898)). I then found out, that when I comment the `@Comment(...)` annotation out, the query runs smoothly again.

Am I making any mistake, or is this normal behaviour?

**NOTE**

When I compared times of execution, there was only 3 entities in the table. Here is the log of execution time of the methods:

```
Execution time of convertToEntityAttribute: 5193
Execution time of convertToEntityAttribute: 0
Execution time of convertToEntityAttribute: 0
Execution time of convertToEntityAttribute: 0
```

For some reason, it takes almost 5.2s to encrypt for the first time - then, the time is smaller than 1 millisecond.

Comment: did you try to check the time of your converter?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa, I've posted the execution time logs

Answer (score 0):

Use jvisualvm (included in oracle jvm distribution) to pinpoint what is slow.

Use the `Sampler` tab, click on the `CPU` button just before triggering the slow operation (once without the `@Convert`, once with the annotation), and click on the `Stop` and then `snapshot` button when the operation is finished. Then compare both execution profile. You'll see exactly what method is taking time.

It could be a lazy initialization the first time you use the encryption tool, or hibernate, or anything else.

If you have a hard time analyzing the cpu sampling result, do not hesitate to come back here and update your question with it (you can export the snapshot).

---

Not related to your issue, i'm not sure it is advised to ignore exception at conversion (you return `null` in case of exception) : you might lose data.

Also, avoid doing that :

```
 System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
```

For example, in case of `NullPointerException`, you'll get on the console : `Error while encrypting: java.lang.NullPointerException: null`. A nullpointer is really simple to fix, provided you have the stacktrace. Here you will have to guess where it happened.